# Digicert EV SSL allows subdomain no need for wildcard or SANs?

Tags: ssl

I have a DigiCert Basic EV Certificate.
TLS/SSL and I want to add a subdomain, without adding a SANs or Wildcard. It's possible??

my license is this.
https://www.digicert.com/tls-ssl/basic-tls-ssl-certificates

Comment: Just ditch them and go with https://letsencrypt.org/. Essentially unlimited, free.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Let's Encypt don't issue EV certificates - only DV.

Comment: @garethTheRed No one cares about EV certificates; both Chrome and Firefox have already removed the indicators that it's an EV cert. https://www.troyhunt.com/extended-validation-certificates-are-really-really-dead/

Comment: @ceejayoz True, it was a great money spinner while it lasted :-) But the question asked about EV, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add any additional SAN dnsNames or a wildcard dnsName then your only other option is to purchase/obtain a new certificate for the subdomain.

This doesn't depend on who issued the certificate or the licence - it's simply how certificates work.

Comment: Okey! Thx resolved my problem.